# C# how to get a datatable from IQueryable<T> including multi object lists

Tags: c#

I have a IQueryable list, which includes some objects lists. I want get a DataTable from the list and shows as a table.

```
IQuerable<Load> loads;
public class Load
{        
    public int LoadID { get; set; }        
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }      
    public List<PickUp> ShipperPickUps { get; set; }
    public List<Deliver> ConsigneeDelivers { get; set; }
    public List<string> ReferenceNumbers { get; set; }
    ...        
}

public class PickUp
{
    public int? LoadID { get; set; }
    public int? ShipperID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }     
    ...
}

public class Deliver
{
    public int? LoadID { get; set; }
    public int? ConsigneeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now the data like this

```
IQuery<Load>:
{
  {
    LoadID:1,
    LoadNumber:"0001",
    CustomerName:"Customer1",
    Pickup:
      {
         {LoadID:1,ShipperID:1,Name:"Shipper1"...},
         {LoadID:1,ShipperID:2,Name:"Shipper2"...},
          ...              
      }
    Deliver:
      {
         {LoadID:1,ConsigneeID :1,Name:"Consignee1"...},
         {LoadID:1,ConsigneeID :2,Name:"Consignee2"...},
         ...
      }
    ReferenceNumbers:
      {
         "Reference1",
         "Reference2",
          ...
      }
 },
 {
    LoadID:2,
    LoadNumber:"0002",
    CustomerName:"Customer2",
    Pickup:
      {
         {LoadID:2,ShipperID:3,Name:"Shipper3"...},
         {LoadID:2,ShipperID:4,Name:"Shipper4"...},
          ...
      }
    Deliver:
      {
         {LoadID:2,ConsigneeID :3,Name:"Consignee3"...},
         {LoadID:2,ConsigneeID :4,Name:"Consignee4"...},
         ...
      }
    ReferenceNumbers:
      {
         "Reference3",
         "Reference4",
          ...
      }
  },
  ...
}
```

I defined a class:

```
public class ExportData
{        
  public int LoadID { get; set; }
  public string LoadNumber { get; set; }    
  public string CustomerName { get; set; }   
  public string ShipperName{ get; set; }
  public string  DeliverName{ get; set; }
  public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
  ...        
}
```

I want get another IQuerable list or Datatable like this:

```
IQuerable<ExportData>:
{
  {
    LoadID:1,
    LoadNumber:"0001",
    CustomerName:"Customer1",
    ShipperName:"Shipper1",
    DeliverName:"Consignee1",
    ReferenceNumber:"Reference1"
    ...
  },
  {
    LoadID:1,
    LoadNumber:"0001",
    CustomerName:"Customer2",
    ShipperName:"Shipper2",
    DeliverName:"Consignee2",
    ReferenceNumber:"Reference2"
    ...
  },
  {
    LoadID:2,
    LoadNumber:"0002",
    CustomerName:"Customer3",
    ShipperName:"Shipper3",
    DeliverName:"Consignee3",
    ReferenceNumber:"Reference3"
    ...
  },
  {
    LoadID:2,
    LoadNumber:"0002",
    CustomerName:"Customer4", 
    ShipperName:"Shipper4",
    DeliverName:"Consignee4",
    ReferenceNumber:"Reference4"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

I tried

```
IQueryable<ExportData> exportData;
exportData = loads
    .Select(load => new ExportData
     {
         LoadID = load.LoadID,
         LoadNumber = load.LoadNumber,
         CustomerName = load.CustomerName,
         ...
      });
```

But I have no idea about the Object lists. Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you match `Pickup`/ `Deliver` / `Reference` between each other?

Comment: That's the problem. Now I just match them in order.

Comment: You need some sort of `LoadConsigmentTable` in the middle with `LoadID, ShipperId,DeliveryId,ReferenceId'`

Comment: Hi, Michal. That's the result I want get. list loadID, ShipperId, DeliveryId,ReferenceId. Each LoadID has serveral shipper,delivery and reference. They match in order. That means in one loadID, First shipper matches first delivery and first Reference. Second Shipper matches second Delivery and second Referenc.